# GET request in JSF

Tags: jsf, get

I would like to know how to handle this workflow in JSF 2.2 
before i was used to Spring MVC.

so this is my workflow:
i send get request with id parametre , controller receive the id , with some logic decide the page to visit so i return the String

```
GET request?id=xxx ----> Controller receive id ----> return page based on id
```

Now in JSF i able to do this only with post and action , is there any way to do so with GET instead of post , with action for example which return string to the page

```
<h:link action="..." />
```

Comment: If you know the `id` before rendering the view, just render the appropiate link for it. If you don't, you'll need to perform a POST.

Comment: As Xtreme Biker said, use <h:link ... outcome="#{bean.nextpage}"> where nextpage() returns the navigation case (String) based on the id